# jQuery Validation: how to make the amount of characters no include the tokens generated by CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-validate, ckeditor

In my Rails app, I want to use jQuery Validation plugin for CKEditor's data,  it works fine except `a little inappropriate count` including the tokens generated by CKEditor. The following is main code:

http://jsfiddle.net/sscs1kbx/3/

Html:

```
  <textarea name="answer[content]" class="required" id="editor1"></textarea>
  <script> CKEDITOR.replace('answer[content]');</script>
  <br />
```

javascript:

```
$('#add-job').validate({
   ignore: [],         
   rules: {
          "answer[content]": {required: function(){CKEditorUpdate();},
                            minlength: 18 }
        },
   messages: {
                "answer[content]": "Required at least 10 characters"
             },
  });

function CKEditorUpdate(){
    for(instance in CKEDITOR.instances){
       CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
     }
}
```

Here, `minlength` is set `minlength: 18`, but I only can input `11` characters `ddddddddddd`, so I guess the final textarea's characters count includes the tokens such as `<p></p>`, but I hope jQuery Validation only includes the characters user input, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally resolve it, because simply setting some parameters can not exclude the html tokens, I used `addMethods` to specify a method called `minlengthxo` for it:    http://jsfiddle.net/sscs1kbx/4/

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("minlengthxo", function (value, element,param) {
  originalVal = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData().replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
  var length = $.isArray( originalVal ) ? value.length : this.getLength( originalVal, element );
  return length >= param;
}, "default errorMessage");

$('#add-job').validate({

ignore: [],         
rules: {
        "answer[content]": {
            required: function() 
                     {
                       CKEditorUpdate();                        
                     }, 
                     minlengthxo: 18
                }
            },
            messages: {
                "answer[content]": "You need input at least 18 characters, now you entered "
            },
        });

    function CKEditorUpdate(){
       for(instance in CKEDITOR.instances){
          CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
    }
}
```